# execute large git command with batch

Tags: windows, git, batch-file

I am trying to automate some patch generator for a project that I have and normally when there are changes I manually add it to the git repository, commit it and then i generate a zip files with the changed files with this:

```
git archive --output=patch_X_$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H_%S").zip HEAD $(git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT  $(git log master -n 1 --pretty=format:%H))
```

Now I am creating a batch script for Windows that will execute all the commands, but I am stuck when generatint the patch file.

I get an error when I write this line:

```
call git archive --output=patch_X_$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H_%S").zip HEAD $(call git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT  $(call git log master -n 1 --pretty=format:%H))
```

This is the error I get:

> fatal: ambiguous argument '$(git': unknown revision or path not in the
>   working tree. Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

If someone could help me with this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Is your script a bash script (executed on Windows in a git-bash shell session), or a .bat script, executed in a DOS windows?

Comment: it's a .bat script executed in a DOS window

Comment: But... $() is specific to bash, it won't work in windows.

Comment: you must replace `$variables` with batch variables: `%var%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is just for your personal use you might consider to install cygwin and just run the original shell/bash script on windows.

of course, if it is meant for the general public, i do not know if you can expect them to install cygwin.

Comment: Yes, it will be mostly for personal use so I think this will be the best option. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax $() is Unix/Linux specific as it launch a sub shell to execute the given command.

Unfortunately I don't know the equivalent on Windows